# Issue creating new user on MySQL

Tags: mysql

When I create a new user on my MYSQL database I get:

```
mysql> CREATE USER ‘sometime’@‘localhost' IDENTIFIED BY ‘mypass’;
```

But instead of getting:

> Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

I get:

> '>

Which makes does not allow any entries.

I am looking how to get back to:

> mysql>

I am sure this is a simple issue I am missing.  I have done this a lot before, but this is a new database instance.  Help would be appreciated

Comment: try  replacing  `‘` and `’` with `'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is problem with your SQL syntax . You are using incorrect single quotes " ‘ " in the starting of string.

Please use below query.

CREATE USER 'sometime'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';

I hope , this will be helpful for you.